# How to load image from database in orbeon form

Tags: orbeon

I have created webservice that produce xml which contain student id and image in encoded string:

```
<formDetail>
<documentId>333333</documentId>
<encodedImage>
 image in encode string
</encodedImage>
</formDetail>
```

I want to display this information in initial form load
 in orbeon form I have following model

```
<xf:model>
    <xf:instance id="formDetails-instance">
        <formDetails xmlns="">
            <formDetail>
                <documentId/>
                <encodedImage/>
            </formDetail>
        </formDetails>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:instance id="formDetail-template">
        <formDetail xmlns="">
            <documentId/>
            <encodedImage/>
        </formDetail>
    </xf:instance>

    <xf:submission id="load-data-submission" method="get"
      serialization="none" mediatype="application/xml"
      resource="http://localhost:8080/webformservice/services/config/xml/barcode/333333"
      replace="instance" instance="formDetail-template"/>
  </xf:model>
```

in body I have set value as follows

```
      <xf:group ref="formDetail">
        <xf:input ref="formId">
            <xf:label ref="instance('formDetail-template')/formId"/> 
        </xf:input>
       <xh:img class="site-navigation" src="xxf:instance('formDetail-template')/formDetail/encodeImage"/>           
      </xf:group>
```

Image is not display

How can I load image from DB basically I want to load data from webservice with image detail as byte stream (encoded string) and display it in orbeon form

Answer (score 0):

If the URL of the image is reachable from the browser, you can do it this way:

```
<xh:img
    class="site-navigation"
    src="{xxf:instance('formDetail-template')/formDetail/encodeImage}"/>
```

Otherwise, instead of using `xh:img`, try the following:

```
<xf:output
    mediatype="image/*"
    ref="xxf:instance('formDetail-template')/formDetail/encodeImage"/>
```